# Saltstack: how to launch "apt-get upgrade" with cache expiration time?

Tags: apt, salt-stack

I've been unable to find in docs, how can I launch `apt-get update` with cache expiration. In ansible it's quite easy to achieve:

```
 - name: Update APT cache
    apt: update_cache=yes cache_valid_time=86400 # 24 hours
```

Would be nice to know how to achieve this with saltstack. I'm using vagrant in here, it's pretty wise to put this into sharable folder, so you won't need to do this for each vm you have.

Comment: Why downvote? Where can I ask questions about saltstack?

Answer (score 0):

Interesting.  The following should work:

```
{% set time_then = salt['file.stats']('/var/cache/apt/pkgcache.bin')['mtime'] -%}
{% set time_now = salt['cmd.run']('date +"%s"')|float -%}
{% set time_diff = (time_now - time_then) -%}
{% if time_diff > 60*60*2 -%}
apt_get_update_if_2_hours_stale:
  cmd.run:
    - name: apt-get update -qqy
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 0):

May be done with:

```
apt_update_cache:
  module.run:
    - name: pkg.refresh_db
    - pkg.refresh_db:
      - cache_valid_time: 500
```